# P2P Connection Issue with NAT Traversal on Mobile Devices

Tags: android, blockchain, mobile-safari, nat

When it comes to P2P connections in mobile blockchain applications, there are limitations due to the mobile operating system. Opening firewalls and maintaining long connections is not possible because of these restrictions. As for NAT traversal, it cannot be achieved

However, with the recent updates and improvements in the Android system's permission control mechanism, there are measures taken to enhance user privacy and security. Without root permission, it is not possible to open firewalls, and NAT connections are denied. Apart from using proxies to establish connections, are there any other methods that you know of?